# Error handling produces multiple instances of output statement

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make this program slightly better in variations. I have this program that converts from binary to decimal. How to I change it so that it continually asks the user for the correct code

This is the code:

```
while (nextDigit != '\n') {
    while (nextDigit != '0' && nextDigit != '1') 
    {
        cout << "Invalid Binary Entry. Enter again: " << endl;
        cin >> nextDigit;
    }
    decimalValue = ((decimalValue * 2) + nextDigit - 48);
    cin >> nextDigit;
}

cout << "Decimal value is: " << decimalValue << endl;
```

The problem is, it displays the error message multiple times, not once. It even displays more error messages the longer the incorrect input string is. How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pressing enter after I write the digits right? Sorry it is not clear to me the hint.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what you're doing. I take it if someone enters a string of digits that contain anything *besides* 1 or 0 you want to ignore the whole input and recycle, correct ?

Comment: Yes. I've seen now a previous thread talking about something known as cin.clear() and cin.ignore(10000). If this is where I must be focusing on I should find a different way, it looks to me that this is too advanced for now.

From what I understood in another thread, I should implement those two "functions" inside my loop, so it will clear what cin previous had. Is it possible for another hint?

I think I cannot use this though, as I cannot understand what it means. Ah well. I will keep at it until it works.

Comment: Its not that bad. honestly. If I get a chance I'll whip something up, but more than likely someone else already has a solution in the works.